# MySql query Script to count active users in every month

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query for Mysql to find number of active users for every month in a date range. Active user is a user that have a login log records in this month and the month before it (Both Months not only one of them).

here is a scripts for table and test data.

```
CREATE TABLE `logger` (
  `id` INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  `UserId` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `loginDate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `logger` (`UserId`,`loginDate`) VALUES
('1001','20151109'),
('1002','20151103'),
('1003','20151111'),
('1002','20151205'),
('1003','20151208'),
('1001','20160103'),
('1002','20160105');
```

I need a result like this for a range like from 20151201 to 20160201

```
------------------------------
year |month |users |activeUsers
2015 |12    |2     |2 
2016 |01    |2     |1 // only uid 1002 have activity in past month 20151205
```

Ready to use Online Table http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9881

Comment: `('1001','20160103')` vs "only uid 1002 have activity in past month" Which one is it?

Comment: Also a good idea to edit your question and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: @miken32 this one -> ('1002','20151205')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a trick.  Add one month from each date and then you can use `union all` and `aggregation` for the count:

```
select year(logindate), month(logindate), count(distinct userid)
from ((select logindate, userid
       from logger
      ) union all
      (select date_add(longdate, interval 1 month), userid
       from logger
      )
     ) l
group by year(logindate), month(logindate)
order by 1, 2;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I misunderstood the question.  You need *two months in a row* to be an active user.  I understood that a user login would make the user active for two months.  Okay, you can solve this with a `join` or `exists`:

```
select year(l.logindate), month(l.logindate), count(distinct l.userid)
from logger l
where exists (select 1
              from logger l2
              where l2.userid = l.userid and
                    year(date_sub(l.logindate, interval 1 month)) = year(l2.logindate) and
                    month(date_sub(l.logindate, interval 1 month)) = month(l2.logindate)
             )
group by year(l.logindate), month(l.logindate);
```

Comment: here is the result, the  last record is not right http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9881/27

Comment: @Reza . . . This will include one month in the future.  It meats your definition.  But, if you want to exclude it, you can add `having count(distinct month(logindate)) = 2`.

Comment: Ok, It seems we are close to the result but still it gives me a **wrong result**, because **it counts the users that have login in the past month but not in this month, they are not active anymore**, I should get 1 user for 2016-01 and 2 for 2015-12, but your query give me 3 user that is wrong. I test that having line too, it return nothing!!!

Comment: @Reza . . . By your description of what you want, "3" is correct for 2016-01.  The users are 1002, 1003, and 1001.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time But, I have a result table in my question also, I need a result exactly like that, and I think my description say that too, so maybe your solution is relate to another question, I think.

Comment: @Reza . . . Flashbulb.  Now I understand what you are saying.  The phrasing isn't wrong (so this isn't a criticism).  The question would be clearer as "a user that has a login log record both in this month and the month before it".  The "both" would really emphasis the two-months-in-a-row nature of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102751/discussion-between-reza-and-gordon-linoff).